# Grouping/inheriting properties for tasks in Gradle

Tags: properties, gradle, task

Is there a way to reuse property groups in Gradle?

Something that would look like:

```
def propGroup = [
 options.fork = true
 options.forkOptions.executable = ...
]

task compileThis(type:JavaCompile) {
  options.fork = propGroup.options.fork
  options.forkOptions.setExecutable(propGroup.options.forkOptions.executable)
  destinationDir = file(xxx)
}

task compileThat(type:JavaCompile) {
  options.fork = propGroup.options.fork
  options.forkOptions.setExecutable(propGroup.options.forkOptions.executable)
  destinationDir = file(yyy)
}
```

In Java that would be inheritance but you cannot inherit a task from a task in Gradle

Answer (score 1):

It will work if `propGroup` would be defined as a map:

```
def propGroup = [
   options: [
      fork: true,
      forkOptions: [
         executable: true
      ]
   ]
]
```

Then `executable` could be e.g. referred as:

```
propGroup.options.forkOptions.executable
```