# How can I pass a task extension object to a closure in Gradle?

Tags: gradle, closures

Let's say I have a plugin that adds `MyTask.class` and `MyTaskExtension.class` to a project.

`MyTaskExtension.class` has five setters, three of which could be common across instances.

**How do I pass a type of `MyTaskExtension.class` (the extension of the DSL for configuration of MyTask.class) to the closure so that I have access to its members?** My attempt would look like this:

```
Closure commonSettings = { ExtensionContainer.findByType(MyTask) t -> { 
  t.a = "a"
  t.b = "b"
  t.c = "c"
}}
```

Then use this functional `Closure` to apply to instances of MyTask in the Gradle DSL.

For example:

```
task One(type: MyTask) {
  commonSettings.call(this)
  d = "d"
  e = "e"
}
task Two(type: MyTask) {
  commonSettings.call(this)
  d = "4"
  e = "5"
}
```

Related [Grouping/inheriting properties for tasks in Gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28458928/grouping-inheriting-properties-for-tasks-in-gradle)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took the approach of using configuration blocks, which represent `org.gradle.api.artifacts.ConfigurationContainer`, to setup a group of
extension properties.

Either use `configurations.ext` (feature given by `org.gradle.api.plugins.ExtraPropertiesExtension`) if this is a one-time deal (without any other actors involved in `configuration.ext`):

```
configurations.ext {
  a = "a"
  b = "b"
  c = "c"
}
```

OR if you need more flexibility, create your own `org.gradle.api.artifacts.Configuration`:

```
configurations {
  commonSettings.ext {
    a = "a"
    b = "b"
    c = "c"
  }
}
```

Then in a task, just reference elements individually or write some functional code to loop over them. The loop requires that each element in the configuration has the name name as the element expected by the task configuration.

Individual element variant using `commonSettings`:

```
task One(type: MyTask) {
  a = configurations.commonSettings.a
  b = configurations.commonSettings.b
  c = configurations.commonSettings.c
  d = "d"
  e = "e"
}
```

Loop elements variant using `commonSettings`:
This should work once I figure out how to reference the task itself.

```
task Two(type: MyTask) {
  configurations.commonSettings.ext.properties.each { elem -> this.setProperty(elem.getKey(), elem.getValue()) }
  d = "4"
  e = "5"
}
```

Note that the ability to use configurations for this is a byproduct of the fact that `org.gradle.api.artifacts.Configuration` implements the `ExtensionAware` interface somewhere along its inheritance tree. The configuration itself is intended to manage files (each element directly under a configuration is a file object). Configurations are actually intended for managing build output files (which they call artifacts, for better or worse) to be published. See `org.gradle.api.artifacts.dsl.ArtifactHandler`.